# ion-slides methods not working in ionic 4

Tags: ionic4

Unable to use methods provided by ion-slides  in official documentation. checked other answers in here but all seems to confuse ionic 4 with ionic 3 and providing answers applicable in ionic 3.

I want to get active index of slide. online documentation is not complete about how to implement it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Note: Use IonSlides and don't use ElementRef and nativeElement**

Just follow the code below and it will work fine to get the active index from `getActiveIndex()`

```
import { IonSlides } from '@ionic/angular';

@ViewChild('slides', {static: true}) slides: IonSlides;

slideChanged(e: any) {
    this.slides.getActiveIndex().then((index: number) => {
        console.log(index);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In ionic 4, the return type of the getActiveIndex() method is `Promise<number>`, so the code you were using in ionic 3 will not work anymore. You could at a bare minimum switch it out for somehting like:

```
     this.slider.getActiveIndex()
      .then(activeIndex => {
        console.log('active index = ', activeIndex );
        if (activeIndex < this.slides.length) {
          this.selectedSegment = this.slides[activeIndex ].id;
        }
     });
```

Or whatever you want to use it for. The official doc is actually pretty awesome on this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/slides

Comment: Actually, the return type is `number` rather than `Promise<number>`. This has been reported on github as a bug. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/14918

Comment: @SupremeDolphin : Think this may be a case of outdated information: From v4.0.0-beta.6, All methods of all ionic components return a promise.
Now, We can get proper value by handling promise or using async/await. If any *had* slipped through the net in previous releases, they have been captured by now. The code I included above works fine for me: Ionic CLI 4.12.0 & @ionic/angular 4.3.1.

Comment: You're right. When you import `Slides` instead of `IonSlides` the return type is `number`. But with `IonSlides`, it's a promise.

Answer (score 1):

Build the slider in your html with a slides ID and a function which is emitted when the active slide has changed.

```
<ion-slides #slides (ionSlideDidChange)="getIndex()">
  <ion-slide></ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

In the .ts file you import the slider ID with ViewChild and set the function to get the active index.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Slides } from '@ionic/angular';  

export class Page implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('slides') slides: Slides;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  async getIndex() {
    console.log(await this.slides.getActiveIndex());
  }

}
```

Comment: `getActiveIndex` returns a Promise. To see the actual index, use `this.slides.getActiveIndex().then( (val) => console.log(val) );`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but I solved it with the following code:

**My .ts file:**

```
export class RegistroPage implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('registroWizard') registroWizard: IonSlides;
  slideOpts: any;
  constructor() {
    this.slideOpts = {
      effect: 'fade'
    };
  }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.registroWizard.lockSwipeToNext(true);
  }

}
```

**My HTML file:**

```
<ion-slides #registroWizard pager="true" [options]="slideOpts">
    <ion-slide>
      <h1>Slide 1</h1>
      <ion-button>Hola</ion-button>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
      <h1>Slide 2</h1>
      <ion-button>Hola</ion-button>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
      <h1>Slide 3</h1>
      <ion-button>Hola</ion-button>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem like this:

page.ts:

```
import { IonSlides } from '@ionic/angular';

...

@ViewChild('slides') slides: IonSlides;


nextSlide() {
    this.slides.slideNext();
}
```

page.html:

```
<ion-slides #slides pager="true" [options]="slideOpts">
    <ion-slide>slide 1</ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>slide 2</ion-slide>
</ion-slides>

<ion-button (click)="nextSlide()" class="register-buttons">go next</ion-button>
```

exact the same thing goes for the back action

Comment: I think the trick here is importing `IonSlides` instead of `Slides`. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

static: true

```
@ViewChild('ionSlides', { static: true }) ionSlides: IonSlides;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

u need declaration class to app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MySliderComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I used IonSlides as type but it didn't help.
For me, the above mentioned solutions didnt work (ionic v6.17.1). What worked was:

```
@ViewChild('slides', {static: true}) slides: ElementRef;

swipeRight() {
this.slides.nativeElement.slideNext();
```

All methods working this way. Altering ```{static: true} didn't throw any error
If you console.log after declaring slides as IonSlides type, it shows ElementRef type